# Propel 1.6 & Symfony 2: Bundle inheritance and schema dependancies

Tags: php, database, symfony, architecture, propel

I have a src/SiteBundle that extends vendor/CoreBundle, and I want to add a "label" model / table to the SiteBundle schema.xml without duplicating the CoreBundle schema.xml. No problem, you say?! Bah!

The problem comes if the SiteBundle "label" table has a foreign key (e.g. label.product_id) that points to a table defined in the CoreBundle. Propel refuses to build the "label" Model because it thinks it has an unresolved column dependancy.

Is there a way to contextualise the two schema.xml files at build-time so that Propel understands that SiteBundle extends CoreBundle? I guess a simple schema.xml merge is what I'm after...

**N.B.** I've investigated Propel's notion of schema / model inheritance, but none of those solutions fit this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the [Propel Bundle](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle) does let you contextualise the schema.xml files at build-time, either by setting the package attribute of both schema.xml files to the same thing

```
<database name="site" namespace="Site\Bundle\Model" package="default">
    ...
</database>
```

or by setting

```
propel.namespace.autoPackage: true
```

Propel build properties documentation [here](http://propelorm.org/reference/buildtime-configuration.html).

However, my problem actually came from the simple fact I'd misunderstood how Symfony2's bundle override method *getParent()* worked. My problem could be most cleanly solved by leaving the Propel config / schemas alone and by either;

- removing the SiteBundle::getParent() method, or;
- prefixing the SiteBundle schema.xml file with something (anything), so that Propel could get to both schema files, despite the getParent() override.